# Fatal error when accessing Civicrm administrator page

Tags: joomla, core, php7

I am unable to access the Civi administrator section on a website using Joomla 3.7.5, Civi 4.7.23 and running on PhP 7.0. 
Joomla portion works fine, but when I access Components/Civicrm from the Joomla backend, I get a blank page with no error messages (although Joomla debugging is turned on).  Using Firefox Developer edition's debugger the response is "Page has no sources".

I then created a new Joomla user with superuser privileges. Logged in and got the following message (screenshot attached). [image: errormessage]

Since I can't login to change settings to display all errors and turn on backtrace, how do I troubleshoot? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Kate

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/sherida1/public_html/jgs-live/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107
```

Comment: Have you recently migrated your website?

Comment: Hi GrannyKat - you took the time to ask a question, and others make the effort to provide useful answers. It would be good if you could acknowledge them, and ideally Accept (and +1) or let them know via comments why it didn't apply to your situation

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for troubleshooting:

- Debug and backtrace info should also be in your CiviCRM logs, stored in the ConfigAndLog directory.
- You can enable debug and backtrace by adding these three lines to `civicrm.settings.php`:

  global $civicrm_settings;
  $civicrm_setting['Developer Preferences']['debug_enabled'] = TRUE;
  $civicrm_setting['Developer Preferences']['backtrace'] = TRUE;

Comment: You can also set these under menu Administer>System Settings>"Debugging and Error Handling"

Comment: @BruceW ordinarily true, but in this case they're saying they weren't able to reach the Civi admin screens.